# polymer-build gulp build project.sources() and project.dependencies() never "end"

Tags: build, gulp, polymer

```
...
const polymerProject = new polymerBuild.PolymerProject(polymerJson);
...
gulp.task('mytask', function()
{
    const sourcesStream = polymerProject.sources();
    return sourcesStream.pipe(gulp.dest('build/'));
});
```

This does copy my source files into the folder /build succesfully. However the task 'mytask' never ends. It is the same with polymerProject.demendencies(). So I never can do an action that depends on having the build ready in my /bbuild folder. Something like gulp.src('/src/*') ends just fine.

Versions: 
polymer 2.01
polymer-build: 1.5.1
gulp: 3.9.1 or 4 alpha doesn't matter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for this was that in the polymer project were still some errors left. After the errors were solved, the task ended.